# How to parse data in page and return to var using Nginx + Lua

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

can someone help resolve my issue, i'm using (openresty) nginx + lua, and I need using Lua parse html data between `<p>` and put parsed value to var

example: `<p>Total Cost 100</p>` >> `$var`

Answer (score 0):

You might [body_filter_by_lua_block](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#body_filter_by_lua_block) directive, so there should be something like this (didn't test):

```
location / {
     proxy_pass http://backend;

     body_filter_by_lua_block {
         ngx.arg[1] = ngx.arg[1]:gsub("<p.->(.-)</p>", "%1").
     }
}
```